# Rewrite the Next.js example with-react-intl in Typescript

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to rewrite the [Next.js official example with-react-intl](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-react-intl) in Typescript , but I'm having trouble with the HOC component [PageWithIntl.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-react-intl/components/PageWithIntl.js)

My code is here https://github.com/soulmachine/with-react-intl.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Any pull requests is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying the same thing by going through the Basics but got stuck on the "Fetching Data for Pages". There are too many typings missing for TS development.
I created some interfaces for page and component properties and I see that you have too. And the types under @types/next seem to be very lacking/incomplete.

Perhaps its time to write a comprehensive d.ts for next.js/ts?
I am game.

*edit:* just saw that your typeRoots point to src/@types instead of @types. Maybe nothing but still.

Comment: Thanks, fixed @types path. Type system is  a powerful tool but sometimes it gives your a hard time making code compile

Answer (score 0):

Now my code totally works, with only two minor flaws:

- Line 50 of `PageWithIntl.tsx`, `IntlProvider` doesn't have the `initialNow` prop
- Line 47 of `PageWithIntl.tsx`, Rest types may only be created from object types